# Padding on .redactor-editor hides "structure" setting display

Tags: structure, redactor

Trying to use the Redactor "structure" setting: https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/special/#setting-structure

Craft overrides the padding on .redactor-editor, which makes the display a bit broken when using this setting.

https://goo.gl/photos/Qi9HbLmsvyGNGxsw9

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Fixed for the next release and going to vote to close since it's more of a bug than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Redactor puts a "redactor-structure" class in the markup, so to override, I'm putting:

```
body .redactor-box:not(.redactor-box-fullscreen) .redactor-editor.redactor-structure {
   padding-left: 32px;
}
```

Might be nice to have that in the core.